# Why is the google play store allowing people to use a test card on my production release?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-games, production

I had a build of my app in Google Play Open Beta. I released it to Production. Now, even though my friends are downloading it from the Google Play store, and they are not in my beta, it seems to be telling them that they can only use a test card for purchasing! How do I:

1) Close the beta completely.
2) Change it so people are spending real money in my app, when they download it from my app store?

It looks like people should be spending real money, from my beta page -- I've just removed all the testers and changed the country availability to just Aruba. My beta track page looks like this:

[image]

Have I made the right change? Am I just waiting for everything to propogate, now?

Answer (score 0):

The actions I took after posting this question solved the problem. I needed to remove testers, and turn off the open beta test by restricting it to only one country, I guess. All done!